# How can I shake relational database thinking for designing an azure table storage datastore?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have been trying to get a good grasp of Azure Table storage for a little while now, and while I understand generally how it works I am really struggling to shake my relational database thinking. I usually learn best by example, so I'm wondering if someone can help me out. I'm going to outline a simple setup for how I would solve a problem using a relational database, can someone help guide me to converting it to use Azure Table storage?

Lets say that I have simple note taking app, it has users and each user can have as many notes as they want, and each note can have as many users (owners or viewers) as it needs. If I were going to deploy this using a relational database I would likely deploy it as follows:

For the database, I'd start with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Username] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UsersNotes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [NoteID] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NoteData] [nvarchar](max) NULL)
```

I would then setup a relationship between `Users.ID and UsersNotes.UserID` as well as `Notes.ID and UsersNotes.NoteID` with constraints to enforce referential integrity.

For the application, I would have an ORM generate some entities with matching name properties for each of these, and I'd probably call it a day:

```
public class Users
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
}
// and so on and so forth
```

I realize that this design is fully dependent on the relational database, and what I'm looking for is some advise on how to shake this train of thought to use Azure Table storage, or any other non-relational data storage techniques.

Lets also assume for the sake of argument that I've installed the Azure SDK, and have played around with it, but my working knowledge of using the SDK is limited, I'd rather not focus on that, but rather what a good solution to the above would look like. A good starting point will help make the SDK make sense to me, since I'll have a point of reference.

For the sake of completeness, lets say that

- Note data will change frequently when first created, and taper off over time
- Users will have many notes, and notes may have multiple users (not concurrent, just viewers)
- I expect fairly few users (low hundreds), but I expect a fair number of notes (low hundreds, per user)
- I expect to query against `Username` the most, and then show the notes the user has access to
- I also expect when viewing a Note, to show the other users with access to that note, a reverse lookup

Comment: I get the question is "how" but my question is "why"?   Did you price it out in SQL Azure?   1 TB of log file is ATS.   10 GB of relational is SQL.  In between then further analysis.  But 10 GB of relational is a lot of data.

Comment: @Blam I am interested in a learning exercise as well as cost.

Comment: Cool but SO is for specific programming questions.  If you want to learn there are lots of books and online material.

Comment: I agree, there are lots of books and online material. None of them answer my specifc question, thus my post here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some thoughts ...

1. Think of distinct entities in their entirety, and abstain from decomposing them further using any normalization techniques.
2. Come up with a single identifier for each entity, which if indexed on, would allow both an exact key search, as well as a range key search to match.
3. Split the identifier into 2 segments for Azure table storage scalability needs. How to split well,  is a separate topic on its own but usually splitting across well-defined natural segments works sufficient well.

In your example, the two entities would be User and Note.

A UserId would be sufficient to uniquely identify a User. A range search on a user may not be really useful. The user id could be any fixed length value here.

A UserId + NoteId would be sufficient to uniquely identify a note. The note id could be something like a date/timestamp + a GUID for uniqueness. Such a key, in combination with the UserId would uniquely identify the note as well as allow a range search on all the user’s notes or a user’s notes over a given time period.

So if UserId = “ABCD”, NoteId could be  “20120801- 00f64829-6044-4fbb-8b4e-ae82ae15096e”.

You could store both entities in the same or in different tables. Here are some different approaches …

If each entity has its own table,

- For a User Partition Key could be “ABCD” and Row Key could be
  actually anything and you search only on the partition key.
- Or Partition Key could be “AB” and Row Key could be “CD”.

  Both the above would scale well for large number of users.
- Or Partition Key could be “*” and Row Key could be “ABCD”. This would work quite well for a smaller set of users and you could  put both users and notes in the same table.

For a Note

- Partition Key could be “ABCD” and Row Key could be “20120801- 00f64829-6044-4fbb-8b4e-ae82ae15096e”
- Range search here could be

  - On PartitionKey = “ABCD” to get all the notes for a user.
  - On PartitionKey = “ABCD” and RowKey >=“20120801” and RowKey <= “20120901” to get notes within a date range.

**UPDATE**

I misread your question and assumed only a one to many relationship between users and notes. Since there is a many to many relationship would need 4 entities to model, unless you do not mind duplication. (If notes are short and immutable, they can be duplicated and you would not have to model joins).

More than 1 entity can be placed in a single table if the keys are in different key ranges and can be easily distinguished. Although, in practice this is not common unless there is a specific need, usually transactional writes to the same partition (not applicable there).

So a single table schema could look like this. For multiple tables, the Partition Key prefix could be dropped.

- You could also model this in 3 tables, one for User, one for Notes and one for the relationships in both directions.
- You could also model this partially in SQL and partially in Azure storage. Notes and User data in blobs or tables and relationships in SQL.

.

```
Entity        Partition Key              Row Key            
User          “U” + UserId      
Note          “N” + NoteId(Date)         NodeId(GUID)
User Note     “X“  + UserId              NoteId(Date+GUID)
Note User     “Y“  + NoteId(Date+GUID)   UserId
```

These are some alternatives and you will want to determine which fits your data and your needs best.

**YET ANOTHER UPDATE**
Actually 3 entities should be enough with the Note in the UserNote entity.

If UserId = GUID
And NoteId = Date+GUID

```
Entity      Partition Key  Row Key             Note  User           
User        UserId      
User Note   UserId         NoteId(Date+GUID)   Note          (Contains Note and can query for all notes for a user).
Note User   NoteId(Date)   NodeId(GUID)              UserId  (Can query for all Users of a note. Join on ‘User Note’ to get note.)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on how I would store both entities in a single table? Also did you skip my UsersNotes table because it's not necessary?

Comment: @Nate. I misread the questions. Please see my updated response.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. First, my notes are not immutable, users will likely change them fairly frequently. Second, is it wise to store them in one table? If I store them in three tables and continue to model the relational concept, and manually enforce referential integrity in my app, am I defeating the purpose of using table storage in the first place? Also, where does NoteId(Date) come from?)

Comment: Storing different entities in the same table again has advantages and disadvantages depending on your needs. However, rule of thumb is to store an entity in its own table unless you need partition level transaction support. With Table Storage you give up all the advantages of SQL including flexible querying and referential integrity. On the other hand you have huge gains in size and  scalability. So you need to determine if this trade off works for you. Bottom line is use SQL if size, scalability and cost can be met, if not use the NoSQL (not only SQL) paradigm.

Comment: @Nate, In this example, I modeled the NoteId as a combination of NoteDate + GUID to make it unique and sortable over a date range.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense for the sortable bit. Maybe my question should be, "Do I loose the benefits of using azure table storage, by modeling my data in a relational way and manually enforcing referential integrity between azure tables inside my app?"

Comment: No you do not lose anything manually enforcing referentially integrity between azure storage tables.

Answer (score 5):

You can think of Azure tables as collections of objects.

In Azure Table parlance, an object is an entity.

To use your example, users would derive from TableStorageEntity.

Azure Table Storage is not relational. There are no joins. But there is LINQ, a query language supported in various languages. So join operations and referential integrity is not provided by the system. The developer must do this.

Some significant advantages:

(1) Azure tables automatically scale across multiple storage nodes to maintain performance, even if you are dealing with billions of entities. 
(2) They are replicated 3 times
(3) They come with an SLA
(4) The Table service API is compliant with the REST API, so they can be accessed from non-Microsoft technologies.

To allow your objects to be stored in Azure tables, you simply need to derive from TableStorageEntity.

More information can be found if you search for "Microsoft Azure tables virtual labs".

The snippet below ignores (1) partition key (2) rowkey. But this is something you need to worry about. Think of the two keys as being the primary key on a relational table.

You need to think of these two key very carefully. They determine performance. Because you only get one set of keys, you may need to keep de-normalized copies of data for best performance.

```
    public class Users : TableStorageEntity
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Username { get; set; }
    }
```

Check out the hands on. Azure tables are cheap and easy to use.

Comment: ... "don't" need to worry about?

Comment: So, should I just create three separate azure tables, and manually join the data myself via LINQ? In essence just keep the relational setup, just manually enforce it?

Answer (score 1):

Why does UsersNotes have an ID?  Why not just UserID, NoteID as a composite primary key?

So three tables with 2 properties each.  The first is the PartitionKey and the second is the RowKey.

If you expect to query on NoteID to get UserIDs a lot then a 4th table as search on PartitionKey is faster than search on RowKey.  And it will usually be cheaper as it results in less transactions.  But you have the transactions to load the table.

```
public class NotesUsers : TableStorageEntity
    {
        public int NoteID { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
    }
```

And for the Users table go with UserName as the PartitionKey if that is the common query condition.

The is no declarative referential integrity in ATS.   You will need to enforce all data relations in your application.   Two part composite key.  A search on the RowKey is like a scan (not a seek).  Where a search on the PartitionKey is like a seek.

But I would go SQL. If notes is someone typing then that is a relative low volume of data.  And it is relational data.

Comment: UsersNotes has an ID out of protocol/habit. It isn't explicitly needed I suppose. I understand referential integrity must be implemented in my app's code. Maybe my question should be, "Do I loose the benefits of using table storage, by modeling my relational data in it and manually enforcing referential integrity?" -- I was under the impression that to effectively use ATS, you had to model your data differently (non-relational) but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: If ID is not needed then why use it UsersNotes.  Back to my original comment of SO is for specific programming questions.  Did you read my answer?   The addition table NotesUsers is an example of how the table model be would different in ATS from SQL.  In SQL I would not put username first.